# Overriding styled-components with `css` prop in Emotion

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

I'm trying to override the base styles of an [Emotion styled component](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled) with some inline styles - specifically a `css` prop. The inline styles are not applied using the `css` prop however, and the only method I've found to work is using a `styles` prop.

Here's a basic example:

```
const Content = styled.div`
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
`
// 50px of padding
<Content>
  Hello CodeSandbox
</Content>

// 50px of padding
<Content css={css`padding: 20px;`}>
  With Override
</Content>

// 50px of padding
<Content css={{ padding: '20px' }}>
  With Override
</Content>

// 20px of padding, but with an inline style
<Content style={{ 'padding': '20px' }}>
  With Override
</Content>
```

And here's a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/emotion-playground-5o66x)

How do we override the styles of a styled component so the inline style is bundled with the generated class from Emotion?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Emotion, but my guess is that you can't update the bundled style with inline css/styles.  The style for the styled component gets compiled/created before the jsx executes.  And think about it this way: if a jsx inline-style modified the class that was assigned to a component, what happens to other components that share the class?  Having an inline-style change a pre-defined class sounds dangerous and undesirable.

Comment: That makes sense now that you say it. I guess I'll need to make the styled component accept a `prop` for conditionally setting the specific styles I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

[As described in the Emotion docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop), the `css` prop requires a little more work than just including it. There are a few different way to work with it, but one way is to include the JSX pragma to tell the compiled `jsx` to use emotion's function instead of React's default.

I've forked your Codesandbox with an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/emotion-playground-forked-kyhz4